# Paragraph is not readable in Edge with narrator

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, narrator

I'm trying to use ARIA Labels for accessibility by the way paragraph tag is working fine in chrome using narrator tool, but is not readable in Edge. I'm not using any aria attribute for this type of element; should I use it if I want to read the content?

```
<aside>
     <img class="logo"  title="bla" alt="Bla" src="logo.svg" tabindex="0" />     
     <h1 tabindex="0">Welcome</h1>
     <p tabindex="0">blah bla blah</p>
     <p tabindex="0" >bla blha</p>

<aside><!-- aside -->
```

Comment: `but is not readable in Edge.` Can you give a working example ?

Comment: I mean when the user uses tab key in chrome narrator reads the content of the paragraph but not in Edge browser

Comment: There is only partial support.. https://caniuse.com/#feat=wai-aria its browser related. and not a development issue im afraid.

Comment: I think should to be different think I'm not using any aria attribute in those paragraphs and the version of Edge that I'm using is 17.17134 so it's supposed to be supported

Comment: Its only partially supported, try some more simple combinations and a minimal reproducable example for the question please

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your above code in Edge with Narrator tool.

In my test, I can see that Narrator tool can read the text from paragraph and it also read the next paragraph when user press TAB key.

Below is my testing result.

[image]

I suggest you to start tabindex from 1 instead of 0 and check whether it may help or not.

I have a question that are you using the same code that you had posted above?

If not, Try to provide the exact sample code that you are testing on your side and also provide a detailed steps to produce the issue.

We will try to follow that steps and try to make a test again to produce the issue.

Comment: I edited the code. The h1 elements and alt image is working fine but <p> tag, not I'm not sure if it can be because of the display property of the element

Answer (score 0):

I again made a test with your updated code.

Still I am getting the similar results as before.

Narrator is able to read the text from paragraph tag in Edge.

below is a new testing result.

[image]

Here, I want to suggest you to check for a latest updates and if any available then install it and then try to make a test.

It is possible that you are using any older version has this issue with it and in latest version this issue got solved.

You can also try to post video of your testing result, so that we can also see what going on there.